# Cell in UITableView stays highlighted when popping back to ViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I have a `ViewController` with a `UITableView`. I select a cell to move to another `ViewController` but when I'm popping back using `[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO];` The cell that I selected is still highlighted with blue. The only way to unhighlight it is to select another cell. How can I clear the highlighted blue on selection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `deselectRowAtIndexPath:` method in your `didSelectrowAtIndexPath` or so.

```
 [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
```